# Proving a greedy algorithm of finding MINIMAL group

Tags: algorithm-analysis, greedy-algorithms

I am given a group $A$ of real numbers and I have to find the minimal group $B$ such that for each $a$ in $A$ there exists at least one $b$ in $B$ such that $|a-b|\leq 1$

So what I think the algorithm should do is first sort $A$, then insert $A[0]+1$ to $B$, and then iterate on $A$ and check if the last number we added to $B$ is still in his radius of $1$. If not - insert a new number to $B$ that will be that $A[i]+1$. The complexity is of course $O(n \log(n))$ because we have to sort $A$.

Now I have to prove that the algorithm gives us indeed the minimal group $B$. And here I am stuck. If there is a better solution (an algorithm that gives us a smaller group), then we can change the number of elements in $B$ and reorganize them so that they will cover more elements in $A$ using less elements then we originally had. How do I write a formal explanation?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami changed it a bit - is it more understandable now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a number $m$ a milestone if it is in $A$ and your greedy algorithm adds $m+1$ to $B$.

The greedy algorithm selects each next milestone so that it is greater than the current milestone${}+1+1$. So any two milestones are more than 2 apart.

Hence each number in any solution can cover at most one milestone. Any solution must add at least one distinct number for each milestone.

Since the greedy algorithm adds exactly one number for each milestone, it is optimal.